# How to display data from clicked container to other con

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

**Can someone help me to display specific song while clicking on that in Your Playlist container on the left??**

I am trying to list data on the left in Your Playlist container When I click on one of the music it should show it in Your Playlist container. It has to save it to browser history as well and it has to remove it from Search because it is already gonna be in Your Playlist container. I will deploy it later to Firebase but now I need help.
It should be added to the left while clicking on one of the listed songs after a search.
Please support me on that.

[image]

I am adding my codes here as well for my project:

**I have App.js**

```js
import "./App.css";
  
import MySongs from "./MySongs.js";
import Search from "./Search.jsx";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     
      <div className="body">
        <MySongs />
        <Search />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```css
.App {
  background-color: #303030;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.body {
  display: flex;
}
```

I have **Search.jsx**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./Search.css";
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { IoSearch,IoClose } from "react-icons/io5";
import {motion, AnimatePresence} from "framer-motion";
import {useClickOutside} from "react-click-outside-hook";
import MoonLoader from 'react-spinners/MoonLoader';
import { useDebounce } from "./hooks/debounceHook";
import axios from "axios";
import { TvShow } from "./tvShow";

const SearchBarContainer = styled(motion.div)`
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 96%;
  height: 2.5em;
  background-color: #424242;
  border-radius: 3px;
  
`;

const SearchInputContainer = styled.div`
  width: 98%;
  min-height: 2.5em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2px 15px;
`;

const SearchInput = styled.input`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: transparent;
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
    &::placeholder {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
  &::placeholder {
    color: #white;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  }
`;

const SearchIcon = styled.span`
  color: #bebebe;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  vertical-align: middle;
`;

const CloseIcon = styled(motion.span)`
  color: #bebebe;
  font-size: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    color: #dfdfdf;
  }
`;

const LineSeperator = styled.span`
  display: flex;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 2px;
  background-color: #d8d8d878;
`;

const SearchContent = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow-y: auto;
`;

const LoadingWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
`;

const WarningMessage = styled.span`
  color: #a1a1a1;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
`;

const containerVariants = {
  expanded: {
    height: "26em",
  },
  collapsed: {
    height: "2.5em",
  },
};

const containerTransition = { type: "spring", damping: 22, stiffness: 150 };

export function SearchBar(props) {
  const [isExpanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
  const [parentRef, isClickedOutside] = useClickOutside();
  const inputRef = useRef();
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [tvShows, setTvShows] = useState([]);
  const [noTvShows, setNoTvShows] = useState(false);
  
  
  const isEmpty = !tvShows || tvShows.length === 0;

  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target.value.trim() === "") setNoTvShows(false);

    setSearchQuery(e.target.value);
  };
  

  const expandContainer = () => {
    setExpanded(true);
  };

  const collapseContainer = () => {
    setExpanded(false);
    setSearchQuery("");
    setLoading(false);
    setNoTvShows(false);
    setTvShows([]);
    if (inputRef.current) inputRef.current.value = "";
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isClickedOutside) collapseContainer();
  }, [isClickedOutside]);

  

  const searchTvShow = async () => {
    if (!searchQuery || searchQuery.trim() === "") return;

    setLoading(true);
    setNoTvShows(false);

    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://deezerdevs-deezer.p.rapidapi.com/search',
      params: {q: searchQuery},
      headers: {
        'x-rapidapi-host': 'deezerdevs-deezer.p.rapidapi.com',
        'x-rapidapi-key': '6a99d5e101msh1e9f2b2f948746fp1ae1f3jsn6b458fe8b4e4'
      }
    };
    
    axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
      
      if (response) {
        
        if (response.data && response.data.length === 0) setNoTvShows(true);
        
        setTvShows(response.data.data);
      }
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error);
    });

    

    setLoading(false);
  };

  useDebounce(searchQuery, 500, searchTvShow);
//  console.log(tvShows);
  return (
    
    <div className="my__search">
    <SearchBarContainer
      animate={isExpanded ? "expanded" : "collapsed"}
      variants={containerVariants}
      transition={containerTransition}
      ref={parentRef}
    >
      <SearchInputContainer>
        <SearchIcon>
          <IoSearch />
        </SearchIcon>
        <SearchInput
          placeholder="Search for Series/Shows"
          onFocus={expandContainer}
          ref={inputRef}
          value={searchQuery}
          onChange={changeHandler}
        />
        <AnimatePresence>
          {isExpanded && (
            <CloseIcon
              key="close-icon"
              initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
              animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
              exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
              onClick={collapseContainer}
              transition={{ duration: 0.2 }}
            >
              <IoClose />
            </CloseIcon>
          )}
        </AnimatePresence>
      </SearchInputContainer>
      {isExpanded && <LineSeperator />}
      {isExpanded && (
        <SearchContent>
          {isLoading && (
            <LoadingWrapper>
              <MoonLoader loading color="#000" size={20} />
            </LoadingWrapper>
          )}
          {!isLoading && isEmpty && !noTvShows && (
            <LoadingWrapper>
              <WarningMessage>Start typing to Search</WarningMessage>
            </LoadingWrapper>
          )}
          {!isLoading && noTvShows && (
            <LoadingWrapper>
              <WarningMessage>No Tv Shows or Series found!</WarningMessage>
            </LoadingWrapper>
          )}
          {!isLoading && !isEmpty && (
            <>
              {tvShows.map((show) => (
                <TvShow
                  key={show.id}
                  thumbnailSrc={show.album.cover_medium}
                  name={show.title_short}
                  artist={show.artist.name}
                  
                />
              ))}
            </>
          )}
        </SearchContent>
      )}
    </SearchBarContainer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SearchBar;
```

```css
.my__search {
  margin-top: 20px;
  flex: 0.6;
  height: 450px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 80px;
  background-color: #424242;
}
```

**I have tvShow.jsx**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import {ImDownload} from "react-icons/im";

const TvShowContainer = styled.div`
  width: 96%%;
  min-height: 3em;
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #555555;
    align-items: center;
`;

const Thumbnail = styled.div`
  width: auto;
  height: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0.4;
  img {
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
  }
`;

const Name = styled.h3`
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  flex: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`;

const Artist = styled.span`
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 8px;
  color: white;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
`;

const Rating = styled.span`
  color: #a1a1a1;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0.2;
`;

export function TvShow(props) {
  const { thumbnailSrc, name, artist,clickedMusic } = props;
  
  const [wantedMusic, setWantedMusic] = useState("");


  // const [clickedShow, setClickedShow] = useState("");

  // function clickedContainer(e){
  //   const element = e.currentTarget();
  //   setClickedShow(element);
  //   console.log("I am clickedShow " +clickedShow);
  // }

  return (
    
    <TvShowContainer onclick="location.href='#';" >
      <Thumbnail>
        <img src={thumbnailSrc} />
      </Thumbnail>
      <Name>{name}
      <Artist>
        {artist}
      </Artist> 
      </Name>
    </TvShowContainer>
  );
}
```

**I have mySongs.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import "./MySongs.css";

function MySongs() {
  return (
    <div className="my__songs">
      <p>Your Playlist</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MySongs;
```

```css
.my__songs {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  flex: 0.3;
  height: 300px;
  height: 450px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #424242;
}
.my__songs > p {
  color: white;
  opacity: 90%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only partly answering the question: move an item from one list to another (and back) on mouse click.

The basic situation can be solved if you use the parent component to hold the state that the children components display. Then you only need to implement a function that toggles a "flag" (like `selected`), and the components can be rendered based on that flag.

```js
const {useState} = React

const tracklist = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Track 1',
    selected: false,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Track 2',
    selected: false,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Track 3',
    selected: false,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'Track 4',
    selected: false,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: 'Track 5',
    selected: false,
  },
]

const ListItem = ({ title, onToggleSelect }) => <div className="list-item" onClick={onToggleSelect}>{title}</div>

const App = ({ tracklist }) => {
  const [tracks, setTracks] = useState(tracklist)

  const toggleSelect = (id) => {
    setTracks((prevState) => prevState.map(item => item.id === id ? {...item, selected: !item.selected} : item))
  }

  const listItem = (track) => <ListItem key={track.id} {...track} onToggleSelect={() => toggleSelect(track.id)}/>

  return (
    <div className="container" >
      <div className="tracklist">
        {
          tracks
            .filter(({ selected }) => selected)
            .map(listItem)
        }
      </div>
      <div className="tracklist">
        {
          tracks
            .filter(({ selected }) => !selected)
            .map(listItem)
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App tracklist={tracklist} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  gap: 20px;
}

.list-item {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.list-item:hover {
  background: lightgray;
}

.tracklist {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: as It is getting data from API by this way I was not able to get it in my playlist. I need somebody in adding code for solving this issue. it is so urgent ((